# Rails 3.2.8: ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper, Does it exist?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems

I'm developing a Rails 3.2.8 Engine for Comatose for some practice with developing Rails Engines. I've run into a strange problem and I'm wondering if anybody else has ran into it as well. The primary problem is in **ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet#eval_block**. I get an exception of "wrong number of arguments(1 for 0) when the method calls Mapper.new. Here's the current definition:

```
def eval_block(block)
  if block.arity == 1
    raise "You are using the old router DSL which has been removed in Rails 3.1. " <<
              "Please check how to update your routes file at: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/"
  end
  mapper = Mapper.new(self)
  if default_scope
    mapper.with_default_scope(default_scope, &block)
  else
    mapper.instance_exec(&block)
  end
end
```

From a debugger breakpoint, Mapper is ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper, and NOT ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper. However, I cannot find ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper defined anywhere.

I've have no idea if some dynamic Ruby/Rails Magic is happening where Mapper actually has been defined inside RouteSet by a some gem. I cannot seem to track that, and I've grep searched for "Mapper" in the entire gemset and could not find anything.

I've actually had to create a work around in my code with an initializer in test/dummy/config/initializer so that Mapper is fully qualified.

```
::ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet.class_eval do
    def eval_block(block)
      if block.arity == 1
        raise "You are using the old router DSL which has been removed in Rails 3.1. " <<
                  "Please check how to update your routes file at: http://www.engineyard.com/blog/2010/the-lowdown-on-routes-in-rails-3/"
      end
      mapper = ::ActionDispatch::Routing::Mapper.new(self)
      if default_scopeSo, 
        mapper.with_default_scope(default_scope, &block)
      else
        mapper.instance_exec(&block)
      end
    end
end
```

I've never run into this error before in other projects. This is my first attempt of testing an Engine within the framework, but I've used Engines before in other projects.  The code looks the same in Rails 3.2.7 as well.

Has anybody else run into a problem or am I doing something totally wrong? I'm using Ruby 1.9.3-p194, Rails 3.2.8, and of course numerous gems. I'm on a Ubuntu 12.04 fully updated, and using RVM. The gems from the bundler says I'm using is as follows:

```
Using rake (0.9.2.2) 
Using RedCloth (4.2.9) 
Using i18n (0.6.1) 
Using multi_json (1.3.6) 
Using activesupport (3.2.8) 
Using builder (3.0.1) 
Using activemodel (3.2.8) 
Using erubis (2.7.0) 
Using journey (1.0.4) 
Using rack (1.4.1) 
Using rack-cache (1.2) 
Using rack-test (0.6.1) 
Using hike (1.2.1) 
Using tilt (1.3.3) 
Using sprockets (2.1.3) 
Using actionpack (3.2.8) 
Using mime-types (1.19) 
Using polyglot (0.3.3) 
Using treetop (1.4.10) 
Using mail (2.4.4) 
Using actionmailer (3.2.8) 
Using arel (3.0.2) 
Using tzinfo (0.3.33) 
Using activerecord (3.2.8) 
Using activeresource (3.2.8) 
Using acts_as_list (0.1.8) 
Using acts_as_tree (1.1.0) 
Using acts_as_versioned (0.2.3) 
Using bundler (1.2.0) 
Using cocaine (0.3.0) 
Using columnize (0.3.6) 
Using rack-ssl (1.3.2) 
Using json (1.7.5) 
Using rdoc (3.12) 
Using thor (0.16.0) 
Using railties (3.2.8) 
Using jquery-rails (2.1.1) 
Using rails (3.2.8) 
Using comatose (0.0.1) from source at . 
Using daemons (1.1.9) 
Using debugger-ruby_core_source (1.1.3) 
Using debugger-linecache (1.1.2) 
Using debugger (1.2.0) 
Using eventmachine (0.12.10) 
Using liquid (2.4.1) 
Using paperclip (3.1.4) 
Using responds_to_parent (1.1.0) 
Using sqlite3 (1.3.6) 
Using test-unit (2.5.2) 
Using thin (1.4.1)
```

Is this an issue to bring up with Rails, and if so, where do I do that? Is it a misunderstood scoping rule for Ruby I'm not understanding? Like, why does Mapper refer to a non-existent class in ActionDispatch::Routing::RouteSet module instead of referencing the Mapper class in the ActionDispatch::Routing module?

Thanks,
-Polar

Answer (score 0):

i just ran into the same problem.

In my case, it was caused by a old plugin (savage-beast) which had the following code:

```
class ActionController::Routing::RouteSet::Mapper
  def from_plugin(name)
    eval File.read(File.join(RAILS_ROOT, "vendor/plugins/#{name}/routes.rb"))
  end
end
```

That caused the problem. maybe this can help.
I think the problem occured because of the old RAILS_ROOT instead of Rails.root